# Convert a string to integer with centura SQLWindows/32

Tags: sql, centura

i have an integer variable and i want to convert this variable to string using Centura SQLWindows/32, there is a function for doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SalNumberToStr` or `SalNumberToStrX` , definitions below....

```
length = SalNumberToStr ( nNumber, nDecimalPlaces, strString )
```

or

```
strString = SalNumberToStrX ( nNumber, nDecimalPlaces )
```

---

Converts a number to a string.

- **Parameters**

`nNumber Number`. The number to convert.
`nDecimalPlaces` Number. The number of decimal places you want in `strString`.

`strString` Receive a `String`. The string converted from `nNumber`.

**Return Value**

`nLength` is the length of `strString`, including the decimal point.
`strString` is the string converted from `nNumber`.

---

For future reference here is Centura ( now Gupta, for the last 15 years ) books online :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Gupta\Team Developer 6.2\Books\index.html
```